# Postgres seems to be ignoring my default collation

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to set postgres to sort by collation `en-US-x-icu` by default, so I set the `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE` environment variables to that value. Postgres seems to see them, and say that it's using that collation:

```sql
:mctapi=# select datname, datcollate, datctype from pg_database where datname='mctapi';
 datname | datcollate  |  datctype
---------+-------------+-------------
 mctapi  | en-US-x-icu | en-US-x-icu

:mctapi=# show lc_collate;
 lc_collate
-------------
 en-US-x-icu
(1 row)

:mctapi=# show lc_ctype;
  lc_ctype
-------------
 en-US-x-icu
(1 row)
```

However, unless I explicitly set `en-US-x-icu` as the collation, I get `C` collation:

```sql
:mctapi=# select distinct organization_name from plans order by organization_name limit 5;
            organization_name
------------------------------------------
 AMH Health
 ATRIO Health Plans
 Aetna Medicare
 AgeRight Advantage
 AgeRight Advantage Health Plan (HMO SNP)
(5 rows)

:mctapi=# select distinct organization_name collate "en-US-x-icu" from plans order by organization_name limit 5;
            organization_name
------------------------------------------
 Aetna Medicare
 AgeRight Advantage
 AgeRight Advantage Health Plan (HMO SNP)
 Allwell
 AMH Health
(5 rows)

:mctapi=# select distinct organization_name collate "C" from plans order by organization_name limit 5;
            organization_name
------------------------------------------
 AMH Health
 ATRIO Health Plans
 Aetna Medicare
 AgeRight Advantage
 AgeRight Advantage Health Plan (HMO SNP)
(5 rows)
```

What do I have to do to get postgres to use `en-US-x-icu` as the default sort in my database without explicitly setting a collate parameter? Why is it sorting by `C` even though I've asked it to sort by `en-US-x-icu`?

(for what it's worth: the database in question is an `mdillon/postgis:10-alpine` image running on docker compose. I'd really not like to move away from the alpine image, but I can if it's not possible to use it.)

(update: changing to the non-alpine image changed the sort to en_US.UTF8, as documented in the postgres docker image docs below, and fixed the sort order of this table. I would still like to know why my setting of LC_COLLATE did not change the collation order in alpine though, because I'd rather use that image)

(update 2: the database was created with no encoding options, and I did not manually update `pg_database`, the only thing I changed were the `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE` environment variables.

This version of postgres was compiled with `--with-icu`, as you can see here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/alpine/Dockerfile#L113, and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING certainly seems to me to say that ICU locales should be usable in my version of postgres.

It might be relevant that if I unset `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` and re-create my database, it has a collate and ctype value of `en_US.UTF8`, but that locale does not exist in the Alpine image containing the database, leaving this situation:

```sql
:mctapi=# select datname, datcollate, datctype from pg_database where datname='mctapi';
 datname | datcollate |  datctype
---------+------------+------------
 mctapi  | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8
(1 row)

:mctapi=# select distinct organization_name collate "en_US.utf8" from plans order by organization_name limit 5;
ERROR:  collation "en_US.utf8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

)

(final update: I agree Laurenz about the general brokenness of postgres on alpine with regards to locales, and I really appreciate his eyes on the problem. I still do not really understand why ICU doesn't work as an LC_COLLATE, or why it *does* work when mentioned explicitly, but I've just accepted that I can't use the alpine docker image and have moved to the debian-based one.)

References:

1: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/locale.html

2: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/collation.html

3: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS

4: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_my_strings_sort_incorrectly.3F

5: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#locale-customization

Comment: When you'd create your DB. Maybe you use CREATE syntax with encoding. DB encoding prefferable over server encoding.

Comment: No, the database was not created with an encoding, it was a "CREATE DATABASE mctapi" command with no other options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use any other than the C library's collations in `CREATE DATABASE`. That is an undocumented restriction that will probably be lifted in v13. For reference, see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/3366.1498183854%40sss.pgh.pa.us) and [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/d9d5043a-dc70-da8a-0166-1e218e6e34d4%402ndquadrant.com) thread.

So at first I was surprised that you managed to create that database, since your collation is an ICU collation, which is normally only available through a separate ICU library.

I found a [Silverstripe issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/8641) that complains about the exact same thing, so at least you are not alone. The discussion there doesn't lead anywhere, since they seem to know neither Alpine Linux nor PostgreSQL well.

Further investigation based on your comments show that Alpine Linux doesn't use glibc, but [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/) as C library. It seems that musl's implementation of collations isn't quite completed yet, at least I find this in the [roadmap](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/roadmap.html):

> ## Milestone goals for musl 1.2.0
>
> The following tentative goals for what would constitute “musl 1.2.0” have been
>   established. There is no projected release date for 1.2.0 at this time.
>
> *[...]*
>    - Improved locale and multilingual support
>
> `LC_COLLATE` support for collation orders other than simple codepoint order

This seems to explain your experience.

Using a different Linux distribution with working collations is the way forward.

Comment: Just to clarify that last bit further, here is the dockerfile that builds the mdillon/postgis:10-alipine image. You can see it is a thin wrapper around the base postgres image, just to add postgis capability: https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/blob/master/10-2.5/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: Here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/alpine/Dockerfile#L113 you can see that postgres is compiled with `with-icu`, and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING says that ICU can be used if postgres was compiled with ICU support?

Comment: Alpine doesn't use glibc, which is probably related to the problem; it uses musl. It also says "Any locale name that is not usable for any reason (file not found,
name rejected, error loading, etc.) is treated as an alias for the
built-in C.UTF-8 locale." https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2014/08/01/1

Comment: Ok, I think I have figured it out. I have completely reworked the answer. I feel that I understand now what is going on. Thanks for pointing me the right way!

Comment: The only question I have remaining is why explicitly setting that collation works correctly

Comment: i.e., why in the world does `select distinct organization_name collate "en-US-x-icu" from plans order by organization_name limit 5;` work?

Comment: That is beyond me.

Comment: @llimllib [pg-docs collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html): "A collation object provided by icu maps to a named collator provided by the ICU library. ICU does not support separate “collate” and “ctype” settings, so they are always the same.". It seems, that in this case the database uses the ICU lib, that it has been built with, directly (no os involved). In comparison, when the [collprovider](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/catalog-pg-collation.html) is `libc`, the os-specific info is used.

Answer (score 3):

As of Postgres 15 (4 days old at point of writing), this is now possible.

I posted my solution [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/1004#issuecomment-1280559846).

Short version:
You just need to initialize your cluster with `initdb --locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=en` (you can replace "en" with any other supported locale; "en-US" in your case)

To achieve this with Docker, you just run the Postgres Alpine based image (version 15+), passing in those 2 parameters through the POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS environment variable.

I first solved it with a custom Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:15-alpine
ENV POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS "--locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=sl-SI"
```

and then I just used the official postgres:15-alpine image in the docker-compose.yml, passing the POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS value there.
Example of docker-compose.yml in its simplest form:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=sl-SI"
```

Alternatively, you could probably include those 2 parameters into the postgresql.conf file and pass that into the container.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

Just linking status of this feature https://commitfest.postgresql.org/25/2256/

Comment: Thanks! that hasn't moved in 9 months - does that suggest it has stalled? I don't know what normal postgres timelines or practices are.